# httpful class request not found error occur when i upload to server

Tags: php, rest, httpful

httpful class request not found Fatal error occur when i upload to server, but it is working fine in localhost.

This is anything related to .phar file not supporting server ??
 // Point to where you downloaded the phar
            include($Config->siteurl.'/testhttpful/httpful.phar');

```
        $password2 = base64_encode($password);
        $data = array(
            'password' => $password2,
            'email' => $email,
            'is_active' => '1',
            'phone' => $mobile
        );
        $uri = "http://mm.appexwebsolutions.com/users/register.json";

        $response = \Httpful\Request::post($uri)->sendsJson()->body(json_encode($data))->send();
        $decoded_res = json_decode($response, true);
        $api_message = $decoded_res['message'];
```

Comment: Just to make sure did you do composer install on the server.

Comment: No i din't install. Should i install it.

Comment: Yes then only Httpfull will be installed